# Swift UIDocumentPickerViewController not showing like Action sheet popup

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to access third party cloud applications. my app upload button click to open `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and need to pick files (single or multiple) then I am uploading my server.

1. Upload button click to `UIDocumentPickerViewController` opening fullscreen not opening like action sheet.
2. Need to access all type of files.

Here below my code

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.data"], in: .import)
importMenu.delegate = self
importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet            
if let popoverPresentationController = importMenu.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    //popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
    //popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: why you suppose it will show you action sheet like behavior  ? UIDocumentPickerViewController  is  viewController it will not show you action sheet like behavior that is kind on alertViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation your answer is in below image.
[image]